# encrypt.bat -g "seedtext" doesnt work in command line

Tags: apex, commandline

I am trying to load some data using command prompt, but I cant able to encrypt using encrypt.bat -g "seedtext", below the snippet,

> encrypt.bat -g accs

command promts shows "unsupported option -g", below is the image.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: The [data loader guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_encryption.htm) doesn't document a `-g` option. Where did you see that parameter, and what are you trying to use it to do?

Comment: Hi David, I see this under -
 http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/step-by-step-guide-for-using-salesforce-command-line-interface-data-loader/ - step 1

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you're following appears to be outdated. From the [Data Loader Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_encryption.htm), the switch used to generate a keyfile is `-k`:

> Generate a key: -k [path to key file]
>       Generates a key file, and saves it in `%userprofile%\.dataloader\dataLoader.key` if the path is not specified. Store this file with care as you use it for encryption and decryption.